# Relationships in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have just one week experience in GAE/Java and trying to port an legacy application(developed using PHP/MySQL) to GAE+JDO. I'm now stuck with a basic issue in creating a relationship between two tables(kinds in GAE).

**So here is the case:** 
We have a **Users** table which holds the user authentication information. It also has a field **user_role** which store role_id, which is actually a foreign key of another table **user_roles**.

From the the Entity-Relationship documentation in GAE, I understand that DataStore doesn't support foreign-key relationships and designed the Users class by adapting the Employee-ContactInfo example in the docs.

When I executed the application, the **user_roles** kind is inserted each time I add an entry in **Users** table. The user_roles kind is supposed to have only three static values. But this is having redundant values as I input more records in **Users**.

I think that I'm missing something very trivial, but I couldn't figure it out due to my inexperience to datastore. It would be very nice if someone could guide me to solve this issue.

Here is the code:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Users {

        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        private Key key;

        @Persistent
        private String userName;

        @Persistent
        private String password;

        @Persistent
        private String salt;

        @Persistent
        private Date createdDate;

        @Persistent
        private Key createdBy;

        @Persistent
        private Date lastLogin;

        @Persistent
        private boolean status;

        @Persistent
        private String authKey;

        @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true")
        private SecurityRole securityRole;

        @Autowired
        SecurityRepository securityRepository ;

        public SecurityPrincipals(String userName, String password,SecurityRole securityRole,boolean status) {
                this.securityRole = securityRole;
                this.userName = userName;
                this.password = password;
                this.status = status;
        }

   //getters and setters
}
```

Definition for Roles:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class SecurityRole {

        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        private Key key;

        @Persistent
        private String securityRoleName;

        @Persistent
        private String securityRoleDescription;

        @Persistent
        private String securityRoleStatus;

        @Persistent
        private Date securityRoleCreatedDate;

        public SecurityRole(String securityRoleName, String securityRoleDescription, String securityRoleStatus,String securityBaseType)
        {
                this.securityRoleName = securityRoleName;
                this.securityRoleDescription = securityRoleDescription;
                this.securityRoleStatus = securityRoleStatus;
                this.securityBaseType = securityBaseType;
        }
// getters and setters
}
```

The relevant code from Controller:

```
SecurityRole securityRole = securityRepository.getSecurityRole( securityRoleName);
users = new Users(userName,password,status,securityRole);
iUserRepository.save(employeeDetails);
```

Here is the definition of getSecurityRole:

```
public SecurityRole getSecurityRole(String securityRoleName)
        {
                      PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = this.jdoTemplate.getPersistenceManagerFactory();
                PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
                try {
                        Query query = pm.newQuery( SecurityRole.class);
                        query.declareImports("import java.lang.String");
                        query.declareParameters("String securityRoleName");
                        query.setFilter("this.securityRoleName == securityRoleName");
                        List<SecurityRole> securityRoles = (List<SecurityRole>)query.execute(new String(securityRoleName));
                        SecurityRole temp = null;
                        for(SecurityRole securityRole: securityRoles)
                        {
                                temp = securityRole;
                        }
            return temp;
                }
                finally {
                        pm.close();
                }
        }
```

Here is the definition of  iUserRepository.save():

```
public void save(Users user) {
               jdoTemplate.makePersistent(companyDetails);
}
```

Comment: Except for all the modifications you must have made to the code which makes it not-compilable, I don't see anything wrong. Maybe securityRepository.getSecurityRole returns a copy of the actual role?

Comment: Yes, securityRepository.getSecurityRole returns a copy of the actual role. I have added the code snippet.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show any copy being made. It returns the last role returned from the query.

Comment: As I said, I don't see anything wrong with the code. I thought the problem might be that the repository returned a copy rather than the actual role, but it's notthe case, so it must be something else that I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Users class, you have the defined the property

```
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true")
private SecurityRole securityRole;
```

This statement creates an "owned" relationship in GAE datastore, which means that when you create an object of the Users class, an object of the SecurityRole class will be created as well.

What you need, is an unowned relationship that can be created as follows:

```
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true")
private Key securityRole;
```

In this way, a SecurityRole object is not created each time you create an instance of the Users class. For more information about owned and unowned relationships, take a look at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and it really helped. In fact, I had posted another question to clarify this doubt. I know how to retrieve the "referenced objects" in an owned relationship, but still I'm not sure how to write the query in the case of an unowned relationship. Can you please provide some insight into this?

Comment: You can do that by executing two queries. The first one to get the Users entities and another to get the SecurityRole entities. Then you combine programmatically the results. Also, can you please accept the answer in order to increase our reputation rating?

Comment: Thanks, I did this initially as a workaround, but it looks like a bad solution when compared with JOIN (as you know I came from RDBMS background). However, I need to accept the fact.

Comment: I fully understand, I come from the same background as well :) Hopefully, we 'll be able to provide more efficient solutions as we continue working with App Engine. Glad that I helped :)